# How do I create a DSN for ODBC in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, dsn

I am digging around in a Linux application that supposedly uses DSNs to connet to SQL Server. The connection stopped working and I can't find the credentials that are being used (all I know is the DSN's name).

I am familiar with DSNs in Windows, but how are they created and where are they stored in Linux?

Answer (score 12):

For unixODBC, DSNs are listed in `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini`.  Installed ODBC drivers will be listed in `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`.

Try:

```
usr$ find . -iname 'odbc*.ini'
```

Comment: For me it's `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini`. `.so` libraries in `/usr/lib/odbc/`. Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: for me it's /root/.odbc.ini. You can use odbcinst -j to view config

Answer (score 11):

Simply look for your odbc.ini file. By default it should be under /etc, but I guess it can differ from one Linux flavour to another.

[This](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html) is a generalized guide for Linux/Unix.

Hope this helps.